# extended Bayes formula and antisymmetric coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are $n$ coins, $k$ of them are antisymmetric such that head have the probability $\frac{1}{3}$. Random coin were chosen and the result of the flip was head. What is the probability that the coin were antisymmetric.

So I used extended Bayes formula (by partition: coin symmetric and antisymmetric) and got:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{3}\frac{k}{n}}{\frac{1}{3}\frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{n-k}{n}}=\frac{2k}{3n-k}$$

But my textbook says the answer is $\frac{k}{2n-k}$

Can someone spot mistake in my solution?

Comment: I agree with your solution

Comment: Does a symmetric coin really mean both sides are the same, so either both sides are head or both sides are not head? Or even, some of the remaining $n-k$ coins have both sides head, and some have both sides not head?

Comment: What does it mean for a coin to be [antisymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric)? Can a coin be neither symmetric nor antisymmetric?

Comment: For whatever it's worth:  your solution makes sense, given that you imagine that the "symmetric" coins have a $\frac 12$ chance of showing $H$.  I have tried to change that assumption to match the official solution, but haven't had any luck.